# MySQL mass insert increment one column by MAX of group by of some columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table that is tracking orders/positions of items per user.

There is an auto-increment on the orderID (the PK for this table), a userID (from the Users table), an itemID (from the Items table), and a position so that users can reposition their items in a list and it saves that order.

The table looks something like this:

```
============================================
orderID | userID | itemID | position
--------------------------------------------
1       | 1      | 1      | 1
2       | 1      | 7      | 2
3       | 1      | 52     | 3
4       | 2      | 33     | 1
5       | 2      | 47     | 3
6       | 2      | 100    | 2
7       | 2      | 123    | 4
8       | 3      | 17     | 1
...
```

I want to mass insert some rows when multiple items are created at once and have them increment on the max position when grouped by userID.  The wrong syntax of what I would like to do is:

```
INSERT INTO UserItemOrders
    (userID, itemID, position)
VALUES
    (
        1, -- userID
        352, -- itemID
        SELECT
            MAX(position) + 1
        FROM
            UserItemOrders
        WHERE
            userID = 1
        GROUP BY
            userID
    ),
    (
        1, -- userID
        353, -- itemID 
        SELECT ...
    ),
    (
        1, --userID
        354, --itemID
        SELECT ...
    )
```

Where basically in this scenario the position of the first thing would insert as 4, then the next as 5, the next as 6, etc.

Is there any way to avoid doing one query per insert?

Comment: Why is that the "wrong syntax?"

Comment: Use BEFORE INSERT trigger for this purposes.

Comment: @kmoser sorry if i wasn't clear, i need the position to increment the max value grouped by userID.  This query (while not syntactically correct at all - though it could be changed to be correct with UNIONS) will only grab the current max position, increment by 1, and do it for all of the rows.  So instead of winding up with `(1, 352, 4), (1, 353, 5), (1, 354, 6)`, I will instead wind up with `(1, 352, 4), (1, 353, 4), (1, 354, 4)`.  I need the position (which is not an auto-increment nor should it be since it's unique to userID) to increment with each value.

Comment: @Akina thanks for that advice.  We try to avoid triggers as a general rule, but that will definitely work as a last resort and I hadn't thought of it, thank you.

Comment: @AnneW. Just an idea, not fully fleshed out: could you use variables, e.g. `@c := <expression to get the count>`, and using it like `(1, 353, @c+1)`?